# More on Inheritance & Database Design

Tags: database-design, inheritance

**Foreword:** Although I don't think it's exactly a duplicate, feel free to close if you think this is too similiar to [this previous question from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562040/inheritance-database-design).

I am re-factoring a database design where I have four *superclass* tables from which some others must derive. Now, I am facing the doubt as to if should include (four) "type-identifying" tables and join them to each of the superclasses, so as to identify the sub-type of each record. The problem is that, without them, the design is already pretty big (14 tables) and since one of the requirements is that is must be easily expansible, I fear ending up with a 30-or-more table design. In short... can/may this type of tables be left out of the design?

*PS:* The goal is to have a highly and easily extensible design. For example, one of the tables represents a *message*, whose sub-types can be an SMS, an MMS, an e-mail, a *twit*, a post on *Facebook* and so on. Of course, common information goes on the *superclass*, and the remaining information goes into the other several tables as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to understand 30 tables than 30,000 lines of code.  I've worked with databases that have over 100 tables in them.  I wouldn't worry about 30.

The design of tables to capture entities grouped into a superclass and several subclasses is an example of the gen-spec design pattern.  Gen-spec is familiar to object oriented programmers via class inheritance.  But the design of relational tables to reflect the gen-spec pattern is often omitted from introductory texts to database design.

Fortunately, it's well understood.  A web search on "generalization specialization relational modeling" will yield lots of articles on the subject, including several previous SO discussions.

As you stated, data common to all the specialized entities goes in the general (superclass) table, while data peculiar to a given specialized entity goes in the appropriate specialized (subclass) table.

The trick in the design is the way the subclass tables get a primary key.  The primary key for the subclass tables is not an autoincremented number.  It's a copy of the PK from the superclass table.  This makes it real easy to get all the data regarding a given specialty by just doing a join.  It also makes it unnecessary to include type fields,  since each specialized table covers its own subclass.

This is a little difficult to set up and to update,  but it pays for itself at retrieval time.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depend on the requirements. 
It is not possible to tell if 14 table are a lot or not, without knowing the requirements from the database
Regarding the derivative. A question you should ask yourself if "whether operation on all messages will be a common task relatively to operations on a specific type of message?". If the answer is yes, then you should use the derivative approach, otherwise it is better to have different tables (sms, email etc.) with some fields sharing a common name. 

Regarding the implementation. If you are familiar with [ERD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model)'s (a great method for visualizing your db) IS-A relation, then the common way to implement this is as follows. A messages table will contain all fields common to all messages regardless of their types. There will be a table for each message type and it will contain fields specific for this message type. This will require a join on some queries.
I believe this is what you meant in your question. If so, this is the way I consider to be best.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to design your database around a [properties pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490570/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-the-properties-pattern).  So you could have a `Messages` table that contains all the common superclass fields, and a `MessageProperties` table that allows arbitrary properties to be added to any `Message` instance.

In this case, a `Message` is an `SMSMessage` if it has properties specific to that type (such as perhaps a `destinationPhoneNumber` property).  That makes more work in the server-side code to distinguish between different object types, but it allows you to have an arbitrary number of different `Message` "subclasses" using just the two tables.